# waf multi-step build - target path

Tags: python, waf

In one of our projects, I have a need to build a library, using `waf`.
The library has multiple steps, like it *builds a binary*, then *executes* the binary
to generate a few more files, and those files are included in further builds.
To *run* the binary (which got generated in the intermediate step), I need its 
 path - as string, so that I can prefix to the binary. From the Waf book, I saw an example, and
some references to `bld.path.find_dir()` and `bld.path.parent.find_dir()`.
But these functions do not return path as string. 
And, there is `bld.path.abspath()` which returns the source path as string.

I want to be able to get the path to the binary file which got generated. Here is a snippet of what I am trying:

```
    bld.program(
                source              =       my_sources,
                target              =       'my_binary', # <-- path to this
                includes            =       my_includes,
                cflags              =       my_cflags,
                linkflags           =       my_ldflags
            )
    bld.add_group()
    # use the above generated binary file
```

P.S This might seem fairly trivial, but I come from `make` background, and new to 
`waf` !

Thanks.

**--EDIT--**

I am able to build the `my_binary` here, but I want to get its abs path, and reference it in the further steps

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`build/${build_target}/${your_binary}` - unless you overwrite some default value

**Update#1**

A cut down thing that should keep you going, especially the derival of build targets, also be sure to check the [waf book](http://docs.waf.googlecode.com/git/book_16/single.html) which includes a lot of examples.

```
def configure(ctx):
    ctx.load(...)
    ctx.env.appname = APPNAME
    ctx.env.version = VERSION

    ctx.define(...)

    ctx.check_cc(...)


    ctx.setenv('debug', env=ctx.env.derive())
    ctx.env.CFLAGS = ['-ggdb', '-Wall']
    ctx.define('DEBUG',1)

    ctx.setenv('release', env=ctx.env.derive())
    ctx.env.CFLAGS = ['-O2', '-Wall']
    ctx.define('RELEASE',1)


def build(bld):
            ### subdirs :) under build are usually related to build variant or command
            print (">>>>> "+bld.cmd)
            print (">>>>> "+bld.variant)
        bin = bld.program(...)



from waflib.Build import BuildContext

class release(BuildContext):
      cmd = 'release'
      variant = 'release'

class debug(BuildContext):
      cmd = 'debug'
      variant = 'debug'
```

Comment: you mean, there is a built in variable called `build_target` which points to the build directory ?

Comment: actually you define the build target when you derive it from a context `conf.setenv('debug', env=conf.env.derive())` (not sure how to set it to a existing context though, probably directly via the `conf.ENV.*` variables

Comment: I still didnt get the overall solution :(

Comment: At what stage do you need the path, configure or build? What did you try so far?

Comment: at build stage, I want to get the abs path to the binary, so that I can use in the next set of rules.

Comment: I have the basic framework up and running already. I am also able to build the program, but what I want is, a way to get its path, so that I can use the program in the further steps (without using its path).

Comment: I don't see the problem - you got everything you need - use the cwd, then the subpath as described based on the env buildcontext cmd/variant. To use your just compiled binary, use either the relative path from where you call waf or the abs path. I don't get your problem.

Comment: ok, Thanks for your tips, I finally figured how to get the path to the current build dir. I had to add `bld.path.get_bld().abs_path() + '/' + 'my_binary'`. Looks complicated!, maybe there is a better/shorter way for this which I am not aware of.